# how to explode string into double quote and separate by comma php?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I want to run multi url at the same time, but I don't want to copy and paste it again and again into an array. I want to put it all as a string and explode it in to double quote with comma just like we write in an array.

I want from this

```
$urls = "
    http://
    http://
    http://
    http://";
```

Into this

```
$urls = array("http://","http://","http://","http://");
```

This is what I have done so far

```
    <?php
    $urls = "
        http://
        http://
        http://";
     $url = preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $urls, $matches);
    foreach($url as $ul){
        echo $ul[1];
    }
?>
```

Comment: explode by `\n`. `$arr = explode("\n", $urls);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$urls = "
    http://
    http://
    http://
    http://";

var_dump(array_map(function($s){return trim($s);},explode(PHP_EOL,trim($urls))));
```

Explode the array on a newline, first trimming off whitespace from the beginning and end. Then pass this array through `array_map` where each element is trimmed again to remove the whitespace from each element.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can make your code work with a few changes

```
<?php
    $urls = "
        http://a
        http://b
        http://c";
     $url = preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', $urls, $matches);

    if($url != false && $url > 0 && array_key_exists(0, $matches)) {
        foreach($matches[0] as $ul){
            echo $ul . "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this;

```
$urls = "http:// http:// http:// http://";
$myArray= explode(" ", $urls);
echo  '<pre>';
var_dump($myArray);
echo  '<pre>';
```

you need to add the separator in there

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function on [trimmed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) string or with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag.

```
$urls = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($urls));
```

`\s+` matches one or more whitespaces.

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/465197)